# TCPDF output generates extra blank Pages

Tags: php, tcpdf

PDF generated with TCPDF class has extra blank pages,

my PHP code:

```
$dataname = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'],".php");

$pdf = new FPDI();

$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile("PDF/".$dataname.".pdf");

$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0,0);

$html = "<style type='text/css'>span { font-size: 8pt; }</style><span>$test</span>";            

        $pdf->SetXY(0, 0);
        $pdf->StartTransform();
        $pdf->SetTopMargin(50);
        $pdf->SetLeftMargin(40);
        $pdf->Rotate(0);
        $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
        $pdf->StopTransform();



$pdf->Output("$dataname.pdf",'I');
```

there was an answer with below solution:

```
class TCPDFextended extends \TCPDF {

    public function Output($name = 'doc.pdf', $dest = 'I')
    {
        $this->tcpdflink = false;
        return parent::Output($name, $dest);
    }
}
```

but don't know how to use it. or where should i put this code ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code that is creating the PDF with the extra page(s).

Comment: https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v1/the-fpdi-class/examples/